# Onclick button is not passing props to the functional component React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass props from an onclick event to a function when then renders a component based on those prop values. The problem is that i am not able to pass on the props to the functional component. But it returns undefined

here is the parent component that passes the props using the map function

```
<DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Dropdown Menu">
    {post && (postVideoInfo = post.video_info, postVideoInfo.map((postVideoSource) => (
        <Dropdown.Item key={postVideoSource.id} onClick={RenderVideoPlayer} props={postVideoSource}>{postVideoSource.audio_language}</Dropdown.Item>
    )))}
</DropdownButton>
```

here is the functional component that renders a new component on click

```
const RenderVideoPlayer = (props) => {
    let videoSrc = {
        type: 'video',
        sources: [
            {
              src: `${props.video_url}`,
              type: 'video/mp4',
            }
        ],
        poster: '/path/to/poster.jpg',
        tracks: [
          {
            kind: 'captions',
            label: `${props.caption_language}`,
            srclang: 'en',
            src: `${props.video_url}`,
            default: true,
          }
        ],
    }
    return (
        <Plyr
            options={options}
            source={videoSrc}
        />
    )
}
```

That data is retrieved from an api and stored in setState

Answer (score 0):

It clearly seems like `RenderVideoPlayer` is not being passed any info from the `postVideoSource` in the `map`.

Rewriting the `onClick` as this could work, as you will be passing the props (I am guessing `postVideSource` has the 2 pieces of info that `RenderVideoPlayer` is expecting):

```
onClick={() => {
    return <RenderVideoPlayer 
             video_url={postVideoSource.videoUrl}
             caption_language={props.captionLanguate} 
           />
}
```

I am also assuming this `RenderVideoPlayer` is going to be rendered inside a modal or some overlay or some side div...

Comment: Hey @Bms bharadwaj i tried your answer but it is not rendering anything nor there are errors in the console.log